# R feature selection with LASSO

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso-regression

I have a small data set (37 observations x 23 features) and want to perform feature selection with LASSO regression in order to its reduce dimensionality. To achieve this, I designed the below code based on online tutorials

```
#Load the libraries
library(mlbench)
library(elasticnet)
library(caret)

#Initialize cross validation and train LASSO
cv_5 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
lasso <- train( ColumnY ~., data=My_Data_Frame, method='lasso',  trControl=cv_5)

#Filter out the variables whose coefficients have squeezed to 0
drop <-predict.enet(lasso$finalModel, type='coefficients', s=lasso$bestTune$fraction, mode='fraction')$coefficients  
drop<-drop[drop==0]%>%names()
My_Data_Frame<- My_Data_Frame%>%select(-drop)
```

In most cases the code runs without errors but it occasionally throws the following:

```
Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold2: fraction=0.9 Error in if (zmin < gamhat) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
 
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

I sense this happens because my data has few rows and some variables have low variance.
Is there a way I can bypass or fix this issue (e.g. setting a parameter in the flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a low number of observations, so there's a good chance in some training set, that some of your columns will be all zero, or very low variance. For example:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(222)
df = data.frame(ColumnY = rnorm(37),matrix(rbinom(37*23,1,p=0.15),ncol=23))

cv_5 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
lasso <- train( ColumnY ~., data=df, method='lasso',  trControl=cv_5)

Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold4: fraction=0.9 Error in elasticnet::enet(as.matrix(x), y, lambda = 0, ...) : 
  Some of the columns of x have zero variance
```

Before running below, check that for categorical columns, all of them don't have only 1 positive label..

One way is to increase the cv fold, if you set 5, you are using 80% of the data. Try 10 to use 90% of the data:

```
cv_10 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
lasso <- train( ColumnY ~., data=df, method='lasso',  trControl=cv_10)
```

And as you might have seen.. since the dataset is so small, cross-validation might not offer you that much advantage, you can also do leave one out cross-validation:

```
tr <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
lasso <- train( ColumnY ~., data=df, method='lasso',  trControl=tr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FSinR package to perform feature selection. It is in R and accessible from CRAN. It has a wide variety of filter and wrapper methods that you can combine with search methods. The interface to generate the wrapper evaluator follows the caret interface. For example:

```
# Load the library
library(FSinR)

# Choose one of the search methods
searcher <- searchAlgorithm('sequentialForwardSelection')

# Choose one of the filter/wrapper evaluators (You can remove the fitting and resampling params if you want to make it simpler)(These are the parameters of the train and trainControl of caret)
resamplingParams <- list(method = "cv", number = 5)
fittingParams <- list(preProc = c("center", "scale"), metric="Accuracy", tuneGrid = expand.grid(k = c(1:20)))
evaluator <- wrapperEvaluator('knn', resamplingParams, fittingParams)

# You make the feature selection (returns the best features)
results <- featureSelection(My_Data_Frame, 'ColumnY', searcher, evaluator)
```